# What is the meaning of the sum $\sum_{1 \le x <y\le5} 1$

Tags: summation

I am trying to figure out what this sum means:

$$\sum_{1 \le x <y\le5} 1$$

Up to now, I have only seen sums with a start and endpoint (start and end value) for the summation. For example:

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}n$$

What does it mean if I have $1 \le x <y\le5$ as a lower bound of my sum?

**EDIT:** I have been trying to understand the answer that gt6989b has given but I don't arrive at the same answer. I basically have a double sum to evaluate:

$$\sum_{x=1}^4\sum_{y=x+1}^51=\sum_{x=1}^4(1+1+1+1)=\sum_{x=1}^4 4=16?$$

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong but I am stuck. Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: You can read it as "The number of $(x,y)$ such that $1\leq x < y \leq 5$". (This is of course not a complete answer to your question but you already have one below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum_{1 \le x < y \le 5} 1 = \sum_{x=1}^4 \sum_{y={x+1}}^5 1 = 10
$$

In other words, you always have $x < y$ and $x \ge 1, y \le 5$ is enforced for every valid pair $(x,y)$. Hence, the shorthand expression is $$1 \le x < y \le 5$$ which tightly collapses all constraints into one multiple inequality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have another question about the sums. I understand why the first sum goes from $x=1$ to $4$ (since $5> x  \ge 1 $ but why does the second sum start from $y=x+1$? Why doesn't it start from $y=2$ (since $1<y \le 5$? Also, I am a bit confused how you arrived at $10$. Isn't the first sum $1+1+1+1$ and the second sum $1+1+1+1$ which would give me $4 \times 4 = 16$?

Comment: Or am I evaluating this some wrong?

Comment: @Nullspace the second start cannot start from $2$ because when $x=2$, the pair $(2,2)$ is not valid, since you must have $x<y$...

Comment: But aren't there only 4 pairs: $$(1,2);(2,3);(3,4);(4,5)?$$

Comment: @Nullspace why is $(1,5)$ invalid?

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\sum_{1 \le x <y\le5} 1 $ is the number of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $1 \le x <y\le5$.

It is implicitly assumed that $x,y$ are integers.

Comment: But aren't there only 4 pairs: $$(1,2);(2,3);(3,4);(4,5)?$$

Comment: @Nullspace, no, there is also $(1,3), (1,4), (1,5),(2,4), \dots$.

Comment: Thank you! Of course! I am so stupid... So the full list is: $$$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
x & y  \\
\hline
1 & 2  \\
1 & 3   \\
1 & 4 \\
1 & 5 \\
2&3\\
2&4\\ 2&5 \\ 3&4 \\ 3&5 \\4 &5  
\end{array}
$$$$
I am still unsure how to evaluate the sum though or am I just supposed to count the pairs like I did in the table?